# Can't edit field collections

Tags: 7, entities

I have a Drupal 7.8 site with the Field Collections module version 7.x-1.0-beta2, which is presently the current version.

I'm having an issue where, after I create a new field collection field on a content type, I am unable to edit the field collection. I go into admin/structure/field-collection, and click on 'manage fields' for the appropriate collection, yet the site reloads the same administrative page, which lists all field collections.

I've done some googling, and haven't found any reports of this problem. Also I haven't seen anything in the issue queue for Field Collections.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

**Edit:** I've flushed the caches several times, and tried this on several different sites.

Comment: did you flush all caches?

Comment: yes, several times :(

Comment: You may want to enter this as an issue for the module and see what they say

Comment: I will probably do that. I wanted to make sure that it wasn't just me first.